# Is there Difference Between 1D and 2D in Spin model?

Tags: many-body, lattice-model, spin-models, tensor-network

[image]

The Motivation is That:In the Tensor Network method, they say 'time evolution MPS(Matrix Product State) work quite well in 1 Dimension'.

but as I think any 2D could be expressed by 1D

for example in the 2x2 Square lattice J1J2 isingmodel (2D) to

L = 4 1D lattice.

What is the difference between 1D 2D?

.

Comment: The difference is in the scaling. For a 2-dim system with N spins, you need to contract many more bonds compares to a 1-dim.

Comment: I think you should be more detailed/specific.

Comment: @proton
But any 2D representation could be mapped on 1D.

If I try to calculate (fixed lattice) 2D Isingsystem , I Could unfold from 2D to 1D and then I can calculate '1D' Ising system by using MPS

is there have any boundary for the between 1D and 2D for calculating some fixed lattice ?

Comment: Why is this question closed? It is perfectly clear and a very reasonable confusion...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I don't know... but your answer was very clear to me thank you!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I don't think it is clear what is being asked. (And it is not well written.) It starts talking about tensor networks: So I would think it is asking why certain tensor network algorithms work well in 1D but not in 2D. This is not at all what you answer addresses -- you talk about very general things which give no insight as to why those algorithms do or don't work in one setting or the other. Then again, the OP accepted your answer, rather than the other one which addressed the issue about simulations. Thus, I do think the question requires clarification.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It seems clear to me that tensor networks were the *motivation* for the question, not the question itself. The question is, how can we tell apart a 1d lattice from a 2d lattice since, as OP correctly points out, the latter can be unfolded to a sequence of the former. This is a good question, and not as trivial as it may initially look. People working on e.g. SPTs (which has been a key topic in cond-mat for decades) pay careful attention to such matters, the dimensionality of the lattice is quite crucial, and you need to define things properly if you want things to make sense

Comment: (of course, not that I need to explain such things to you...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, there is no notion of *dimension* for finite lattices. Only a *sequence* of lattices, of growing size, can be ascribed a dimension. For a fixed lattice, there is no way to define the range of interactions and the dimension of the lattice. (Of course, if the lattice is very large, there is an intuitive notion of dimension but it is only approximate and there is no precise mathematical definition. In more technical terms, a finite set has no dimension).

Your argument precisely shows this. In a somewhat formal sense, all finite lattices are zero-dimensional (they are just good old quantum mechanics).

Answer (score 14):

The resulting '1D' Ising system has long-range interactions (while the initial 2D system had only short-range interactions). Approximating the state of the system by a MPS works well for chains with short-range interactions.